# How can I parse the ouput of VBoxManage list usbhost to get the UUID of a device with a particular name?

Tags: awk, virtualbox

How can I parse the ouput of `VBoxManage list usbhost` to get the UUID of a device with a particular name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
VBoxManage list usbhost | awk -v RS="" '$0 ~ "Realtek"' | awk '/UUID/{print $NF}'
```

`RS=""` sets the record separator to blank line (default is newline). `~` checks whether string is contained and the record is printed by default. `/regex/` performs a regex per line (as `RS="\n"` by default) and executes the following code which prints the last field because `$i` is the `i`-th field and the default field separator is `" "` which matches runs of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines, which happens to work out in this case. More information on the special meanings of the values of the separator variables can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405694/default-field-separator-for-awk).